# Does .live() binding work for jQuery in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I have a piece of javascript which is supposed to latch onto a form which gets introduced via XHR. It looks something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#myform').live('submit', function() {
      $(foo).appendTo('#myform');
      $(this).ajaxSubmit(function() {
        alert("HelloWorld");
    });
       return false;
   });

});
```

This happens to work in FF3, but not in IE7. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Could you describe what happens? "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Does it submit the page? Does it not to anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you excuting the submit?  Can you try this instead?

```
$(':submit').live('click', function(e) {
  $(foo).appendTo('#myform');

  $('#myform').ajaxSubmit(function() {
    alert('Hello World');
  });

  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick ben, however the form is never posting to the server. I wonder if that's related to ajaxSubmit though?

Comment: did you try both versions, $('#myform') and $('#myform').get(0)?

Comment: .ajaxSubmit() is a jQuery function. It won't work on $('#myform').get(0).

Comment: This will not let you submit the form via the Enter key

Answer (score 8):

The submit event is not currently supported by [Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

**Possible event values**: click, dblclick,  mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, keydown, keypress, keyup

**Currently not supported:** blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit

Answer (score 0):

Re CMS above, in JQuery 1.4, live is *supposed* to work with 'submit', but seems to still not with IE7.  I'm going to try delegate instead and see if that helps.