# jQuery ajax chained selected not working (Darn you IE!) but works perfectly in FF

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, select, chained

I have a form where the user enters a 6 digit number and clicks the retrieve button.  An ajax call is performed which returns another form of data (no page refresh).  Within the data returned is a chained select (more than one if more than one item is returned).  Below is the ajax code.

```
$(".platform").live("change", function() {
    alert('Updating models...');
    var firstOption = $(this);
    if (firstOption.closest('tr').find('.platform').val() == '')
        {
            firstOption.closest('tr').find('.model').html('<option value=""></option>');                
        }
    else
        {
            firstOption.closest('tr').find('.model').html('<option value="">Updating...</option>');
            $.getJSON("dataCalls/getModels.cfm",{platform: $(this).val()},      
            function(j){
                var options = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
                    {
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
                    }
            firstOption.closest('tr').find('.model').html(options).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
            });
        }
});
```

This is working great in FF but not in IE7.  I haven't tested in IE 8.  Our company standards are still 7 though we are migrating to 8 so it needs to work in 7.

Here is the code which *should* be triggering the ajax call.

```
<th class="form"><label>Platform / Model</label></th>
        <td> <select class="platform required" name="platform">
                <option ></option>
                <cfloop query="rsPlatform">
                    <option value="#rsPlatform.optionValue#" <cfif rsRequestSystems.platform eq rsPlatform.optionValue>selected</cfif>>#rsPlatform.optionValue# - #rsPlatform.optionDesc#</option>
                </cfloop>
            </select>
            &nbsp; / &nbsp;
            <select class="model required" name="model">
                <option selected></option>
                <cfloop query="rsModels">
                    <option value="#rsModels.optionValue#" <cfif rsRequestSystems.model eq rsModels.optionValue>selected</cfif>>#rsModels.optionDesc#</option>
                </cfloop></select></td>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in IE7 error console when loading the page?

Comment: Is the "Updating..." option showing? I got similar code working on IE7, only difference would be the effect I don't have.

Comment: @canuteson No errors, no action of any kind is happening.

Comment: @Louskan - I just added the effect.  Removing it has no change in IE's behaviour. :(

Comment: I added `alert('Updating models...');` just to see if IE was even recognizing the event and it does not seem to be aware of the .platform event.

Comment: Well since it doesn't enter the event, you'll have to give us some more code to see what the context is.

Comment: something interesting is that if I replace click with mouseup, it will work in IE except that it sends off an ajax call on every mouseup.  So odd.

Comment: Simplifying the function to just `$(".platform").live("change", function() {
  alert('Hello World');
 });` still didn't trigger the event.

Comment: @Louskan @Canuteson I found this [link](http://www.neeraj.name/2009/10/14/how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery.html) which references livequery which resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question since I found a work around.

I found this [link](http://www.neeraj.name/2009/10/14/how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery.html) which references livequery which resolved my issue.

```
$(".platform").livequery("change", function() {
    var firstOption = $(this);
    alert('Updating Modules 302');
    if (firstOption.closest('tr').find('.platform').val() == '')
        {
            firstOption.closest('tr').find('.model').html('<option value=""></option>');                
        }
    else
        {
            firstOption.closest('tr').find('.model').html('<option value="">Updating...</option>');
            alert('Updating Modules 310');
            $.getJSON("index.cfm?do=misc.getModels",{platform: $(this).val()},      
            function(j){
                var options = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
                    {
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
                    }
            firstOption.closest('tr').find('.model').html(options);
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments following the question, it seems you have narrowed down the problem to the event registration, seeing as nothing at all is happening, not even the 'alert' is being invoked.

As per the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667812/does-live-binding-work-for-jquery-in-ie7/667875#667875) to another similar SO questions, it would appear that what you are trying to do, i.e. use the live() method on the 'change' event, does not work in IE7.

Comment: Looks like you may be correct.  I'm testing a couple of more ideas.

Comment: I found this [link](http://www.neeraj.name/2009/10/14/how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery.html) which references livequery which resolved my issue.